# C# - IEnumerable Select 1 Single Random Element CPU Usage

Tags: c#

Is it possible to select 1 random element from an IEnumerable without it directly loading in all elements into memory?

I'm trying to essentially pick 1 random proxy from a list of 17,000 KeyValuePairs twice every second on loop.

The KeyValuePairs are: string, bool. Where string is the proxy, and bool is if its disabled or not.

```
concDict == ConcurrentDictionary<string, bool> (btw)
IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, bool>> temp = concDict.Where(p => !p.Value);
activeProxies = temp.Count();
proxy = temp.ElementAt(proxyRandom.Next(0, activeProxies - 1)).Key;
```

The above is what I have so far. The issue here is it results in a lot of CPU usage. The image below is from about 10 seconds of CPU Profiling.

[image]

Perhaps the LINQ .Where's or .Count stuff is rendering all the elements? If so, is there a way to ElementAt like shown, only on Elements with the Bool set to false?

<strike>Only way I can think of right now, is to just do it without the `.Where` and do it in a `while(boolIsTrue)`. Chances are, it will hit one that's false, but when almost all of them end up as true, it would be much worse performance than a where().</strike>
Wouldn't even work as the `activeProxies` count for the `ElementAt` randomizer wouldn't be up-to-date.

Comment: I don't know, Have you tried indexing on it ?

Comment: @ZohirSalakCeNa Indexing? As in, Have an int on the elements themselves that I can reference using? How would that work? I still wouldnt be able to randomize them. unless im not thinking properly here :/

Comment: You're enumerating the collection twice. Once for your .Count (line 811) and again with the .Where(). Why not just enumerate once into activeProxies, then .ElementAt() on the activeProxies sub-collection?

Comment: I don't think you can do that. But a good idea might be prefetching a certain amount of random elements, so you can fetch them at low cost the next few times.

Comment: @DanielleSummers Because the proxyRandomizer needs it for its max value, otherwise it will try reference an element outside the count. (Edit: I see what you mean, my bad. I went with the current way as I assumed it doesnt actually load them all into memory, But if I did it with subbing it in, it would. But I guess it does both ways. Ill update that)

Comment: `select 1 random element from an IEnumerable` get a random index then `ienumarable[index]` that should get you a random value. and skip any enumerations.

Comment: @bommelding It changes very often, The strings almost never and if I do, id know as its manually updated for strings, but the bools are random.

Comment: @JeromeReinländer Not sure what you mean there, Can you give an example?

Comment: I would select 1 at random from the whole dictionary. Then check for value. var proxy = false; do { proxy = ienumerable.ElementAt(proxyRandom.next(0, ienumerable.length() -1); } while (!proxy);

Comment: And how often this list changes (if at all)?

Comment: @ZohirSalakCeNa Yes, but I need to .Where() it so im only referencing ones with bool false, and .Count so I can get a random index based on the count of the ienumerable.

Comment: @Bob Then when that list is almost fully bool, true's I could be looking at an insane amount of loops til I get a bool false. Would definitely be a ton slower and a lot more CPU.

Comment: I could change the entire system if needed. Essentially what its doing is trying to use any proxy that isnt disabled (currently thats by having it set to true as its bool), I could easilly setup another system if anyone has any ideas on how I could do that.

Comment: Why are you using Dictionary<string,bool> instead of Dictionary<bool,List<string>> ? the second one would make it easier to filter out the inactive proxies, and easier to pick a random active one. You could also use Dictionary<bool,ConcurrentBag<string>>

Comment: @ImPRAGMA Example: Read 100 random elements in advance, save them in a queue, work on this queue until it is empty, then refill. You could also do the refill concurrently.

Comment: If you're trying to get only the false ones, use `.Where()` once then get the random index based on the length of the returned list.

Comment: @ImPRAGMA what is the driving force behind selecting a random element in the list, rather than just the first?

Comment: The items in a dictionary are arranged by the hashcode of the key, perhaps just picking the first item in the dictionary would be random enough?

Comment: And do you actually need a dictionary? I mean do you need fast lookup by proxy url?

Answer (score 1):

`IEnumerable` is simply the wrong thing to use here. Instead, use a `List` - that will allow you to count and select a random item a lot faster and with much less CPU usage:

```
// this enumerate the dictionary one and the result of the where once.
List<KeyValuePair<string, bool>> temp = concDict.Where(p => !p.Value).ToList(); 
// now this will be a lot faster...
activeProxies = temp.Count;
proxy = temp.[proxyRandom.Next(0, activeProxies - 1)].Key;
```

Comment: I have some doubts it will be a lot faster overall. Copying items into new array (with `ToList`) is not free.

Comment: "I'm trying to essentially pick 1 random proxy from a list of 17,000 KeyValuePairs *twice every second on loop.*" While it's a lot worse then a single use of `ElementAt` and `Count`, but if you are using `ElementAt` twice every second, you might benefit from having a single heavy operation (the `.ToList()`) and multiple light weight operations (using list's indexer as apposed to IEnumerable's ElementAt).

Comment: Ok, but you need to synchronize that list with main dictionary, because between two checks it might have changed, and proxies that were alive (and marked as such in list) might be dead.

Comment: @Evk good point. in that case, it's probably better to select a random member directly from the dictionary itself.

Comment: Or maybe just use list instead of dictionary in the first place (or two lists, one for alive proxies, one for dead). But I didn't manage to make OP clarify if he really needs dictionary or not.

Comment: @Evk No I dont need dictionarys badly. I could do 2 lists, just im basically worried of them not being concurrent (I am actually using an async/await operation on the loop)

Comment: My main issue here is it being non thread-safe, So lets say we get "activeProxies" int count, and then the list changes, then it will cause an exception if the randomizer selects an index out of range (probably near the maxIndex).

Answer (score 0):

About your question, it's not possible to pick a random member of IEnumerable without evaluating all members before it. Your current code (as said by other members in comments) enumerates twice: get active proxies, then get their count. And possibly a 3rd time when skipping the random number (not sure about implementation details).

A better solution (in my opinion) is to use `ConcurrentDictionary<bool, List<string>>` this will make it faster to get a random proxy that is active, and won't have to enumerate over and over. 17k entries isn't much data to worry about loading in memory, specially that they're simple types and not really large.

```
dictionary.AddOrUpdate(
  true,
  new List<string>() {"new proxy"},
  (b, list) => {
    list.Add("new proxy";
    return list;
});
```

This will add the list if the key doesn't exist, and if it exists then it'll add the string to the list.
You can initialize the dictionary with an empty list and pass it null as second argument to reduce the cost of creating new list on every call, but only do it if you're sure the dictionary has already been initialized.

Comment: edit: nvm, But how would I update it? For example, add a new value to the List<string> or remove a value from List<string>? Wouldnt I need to re-compile and entire List<string>?

Comment: You can use the `AddOrUpdate(TKey, TValue, Func<TKey, TValue, TValue>)` method. And depending on the project it self, you might be fine using a normal `Dictionary<bool, List<string>>`

Comment: Right, But how would I move one TValue (which is now a List<string> not a string) to lets say TKey as true's TValue? Like id need to essentially get true's List<string> and .Add to it, and send it back. Thats gonna be mad slow I bet. (I basically have to add like this, is there no better way? https://i.imgur.com/QyGpcZS.png)

Comment: The function you pass will update the existing list.

Comment: Not sure what you mean.

Comment: I've updated my answer with a sample code. Hope it helps you.

Comment: Null isnt allowed as Param2. (x) => null would work, but its still inconvenient.